# THREE.js Model looking odd on loading with orthographic camera

Tags: camera, three.js, orthographic

I am trying to load a model with a parallel view on using orthographic camera.

```
var camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / -2, 100, 100000);
```

But my model looks odd on rotating it.
This is how my model looks on rotating[image: This is how my model looks on rotating]

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does the actual model look? Also we need to see some code. 

One thing though, the near plane distance `100` seems a bit high. Reduce  it to `0.1` and check again.

Comment: I checked with that too but the problem persists.

Comment: I think you have to share how the actual model looks. Also, share your code. How do you render the model? How do you initialize the mesh? etc

Comment: Your depth buffer range is quite large (100-100000). The larger your depth range, the lower your precision when calculating depth differences. So if two surfaces are very close together in a large depth range, you may see the surfaces clip through each other. Also (and this is a complete guess) are you using a logarithmic depth buffer? I've seen weird things happen with that and orthographic cameras. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733259/logarithmic-depth-buffer-orthographic-camera

Comment: Thanks a lot TheJim. Actually I was logarithmic depth buffer.When I removed it,my model loads fine.Thanks for  Rasheduzzaman Sourov too.

Comment: I am using logarithmic depth buffer for z-fighting problem.Now when I remove the logarithmic depth buffer,I am getting z-fighting.Can you help me with this.

Comment: Please create and accept an answer for this post stating what you found resolved the issue. For the z-fighting issue, please create a new post, and we'll be happy to try to help.